# Update with cross apply in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, cross-apply

I have a table like this in #def:

[#def table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p86SD.png)
I want to calculate the number of days between each service order for the current period ‘201702’ only. Reservice = 0 means not serviced before. The count for reservice increases with each reservice.

```
select 
s1.period,
,s1.company
,s1.prod
,s1.id1
,S1.id2
,s1.serv_date
,t.last_servdate
,datediff(dd, ISNULL(T.last_servdate, s1.[serv_Date]),s1.serv_date)AS [Days       Since last] from #def s1 
Outer apply(
select 
top 1 serv_date as last_servdate from #def s2
where s1.prod=s2.prod and s1.id1 =s2.id1
and s1.id2=s2.id2 and s1.company =s2.company
and s2.reservice = s1.reservice-1 and s1.company =’abc’
and s2.company =’abc’)T 
where s1.company_code =’abc’ and s1.period ='201702'

  update s1 
  set days_btwn_service = datediff(dd, ISNULL(T.last_servdate,s1.serv_Date]),s1.serv_date) from #def s1 
  Outer apply(
  select top 1 serv_date as last_servdate from #def s2
  where s1.prod=s2.prod 
  and s1.id1 =s2.id1
  and s1.id2=s2.id2 
  and s1.company =s2.company
  and s2.reservice = s1.reservice-1 
  and s1.company =’abc’
  and s2.company =’abc’
  )T  where s1.company_code =’abc’ and s1.period ='201702'
```

The `SELECT` query above gives me the desired result. Strangely using an `UPDATE` statement with the same query doesn’t give the desired result at all but only very few rows are updated with values. I have no idea why?!

## def contains list of all orders that have been service more than once.

Edit: Based on @sqlzim 's response I have altered the query. His reponse gives the same answer as well.

Comment: Left justified SQL... So hard to read...

Comment: please add some sample table data and the expected result - as well in formatted text. 
Also show us your current query attempt

Answer (score 3):

This looks like sql-server, so this answer is for sql-server.

I do not see why you would get two different results from those queries, but if you are getting the correct result with your `select` statement, you could put it in a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) and `update` using the `cte`.

Is `serv_date` nullable? If not then `T.serv_date` can not be null unless you use `outer apply()` instead of `cross apply()`.

```
;with cte as (
select 
    s1.ord_id
  , s1.period
  , s1.company
  , s1.prod
  , s1.id1
  , S1.id2
  , s1.serv_date
  , s1.days_btwn_service
  , t.last_servdate
  , datediff(day,isnull(T.last_servdate,s1.[serv_Date]),s1.serv_date) as [Days_Since_Last]
from #def s1
  cross apply ( 
    select top 1 serv_date as last_servdate
    from #def s2
    where s1.prod = s2.prod
      and s1.id1 = s2.id1
      and s1.id2 = s2.id2
      and s1.company = s2.company
      and s2.reservice = s1.reservice - 1
    ) T
where s1.company_code = 'abc'
 and s1.period = '201702'
)
--select * from cte;
update cte 
  set days_btwn_service = [Days_Since_Last];
  /* This will update the underlying table #def */

/* -- Alternate version
update d 
  set d.days_btwn_service = cte.[Days_Since_Last] 
  from #def d join cte on cte.ord_id=d.ord_id
--*/
```

Check the results of the `select`, if they are correct, run the `update` instead of the `select`.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Mostly from 'Poor Man's T-Sql Formatter' in notepad++

Comment: You have a typo there, it's [**notepad++**](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ;) -- on windows anyhow.

Comment: @SqlZim, CTEs! Yes! Thank You. Does CTE update cascade down to temp tables?Select works perfectly fine. Update is still an issue.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I agree I should have formatted it better. I am not good at formatting but I would like to learn. SqlZim's code is so well readable. I will take care of that next time. :)

Comment: @SqlZim  Also, there is a field order_id that can uniquely identify the row to update based on cte result.   Something like this but this doesn't work -                                                                                                                         update d set d.days_btwn_service = [Days Since last] 
  from #def d join cte on 
  cte.ord_id=d.ord_id

Comment: @SKa Well worth the time (for you and future support).  Furthermore, your questions will get more attention.   To my shame, I was guilty of skipping over it.  :)

Comment: @SKa Updated my answer, to join the cte on `ord_id` you would have to include `ord_id` in the `cte`.

Comment: @sqlzim thanks for the tip on outer apply and cross apply. I had to use outer apply as t.serv_date can be null for the first service order. Also, the reason the update was not working was in the temp table #def, the days_btwn_service was varchar(1)! So there was no update to that column when [days since last] > 9.  I could actually use the update statement I posted in my query after I changed the column length and used Outer apply. Thanks a lot again. I am going to edit my question with the answer and vote your answer as well as that works as well.